# Yocto: Unable to run qemu in graphical mode

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, yocto

I built a standard qemu image with `bitbake core-image-sato`.

I can run it without the GUI:

`runqemu nographic` <- works

But I cannot run it with graphics

`runqemu qemux86-64` <- fails, error:

```
runqemu - ERROR - Failed to run qemu: Could not initialize SDL(x11 not available) - exiting
```

But I need the graphical mode!

I'm building with Ubuntu 18.04 + WSL on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know if this is your case, but if you run `qemu` as root, you must first execute the

```
xhost +
```

command as user to authorize root to access X11.

Comment: No. This mean that access is granted to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause of your problem is that you are missing a running X GUI SERVER (X11/Xorg) in your Linux environment.

That is first issue you are having. Normally, for that to work, you just need to start xserver in you Linux box. This is usually simple task taken care of by switching your distribution into graphical mode, which it is setup for by default, usually.

However in your case there is a grave conflation - you say you are running your Linux workload on Windows.

Thus there is a second issue. To know more, to help you, we first need to know what version of WSL are your running:

- if you are running WSL 1, it's quite hard for neophytes and even more experienced Linux admins (you need to know both Windows and Linux quite well) to get Xorg xserver running and exposed into the WSL environment (I managed to achieve this on WSL1 - but WSL is simply lacking as Linux environment)
- if you are running WSL2, the situation is even more complex: while on WSL1 Linux environment is provided (badly) by Windows kernel itself, in WSL2 you are running you "Linux boxes" in a very special multi-VM multi-kernel configuration: WSL2 Linux instances are in a fact very special Hyper-V nodes, ie real VMs.

Unfortunately I hadn't had time to mess with WSL2 much as of yet, as none of my clients needed that, but if I understand correctly, while Linux "emulation" in WSL2 is more thruthfull than in WSL1, I am not sure that you can expose X server into WSL2 environment as easily as into the WSL1.

Finally there is a third issue: the QEMU issue.

QEMU is universal emulation engine which can emulate dozens of processors AND machines and virtual systems, ranging form "desktop style machine" down to "smartphone/raspberry pi" level single board computers.

Now we need to know what are you trying to emulate. From your question it seems you are emulating x86-64. When doing that on the x86-64 host machine the emulation is usually very very slow.

You have to realize that QEMU provides two emulating modes: software emulation and hardware assisted & accelerated emulation.

Software emulation works everywhere, but as already said, for software emulation of x86-64 on x86-64 (which is default), it is insanely slow for any realistic workload.

To achieve near realtime/real hardware emulation speed, we in Linux world, usually combine QEMU system emulation with so called KVM - Kernel Virtual Machine - which you can think of as kernel-side equivalent of Hyper-V on Linux. In this setup QEMU, with help of Linux kernel and KVM, will use hardware assisted virtualization facilities of your processor. I.e. Hyper-V on Windows = QEMU + KVM (and xserver for graphics) on Linux.

But as we already said, if you are using WSL2, you are already using Hyper-V virtualization, so I am surprised QEMU even runs - if it runs, it is either using nested KVM virtualization or you are running in purely software emulation mode. If you are using some special kind of nested virtualization, your performance is severely impacted (twoo/threefold), and if you are indeed running in software mode, your emulation must be so slow, that I am surprised, you are even getting anything done.

So please add missing informamtion about WSL version you are runnign and whether KVM is active in your QEMU setup.

Finally at this level of nesting and complexity I would suggest to you to simply ditch Windows althogether:

- get secondary, real, hardware assisted virtualization capable computer
- install Linux on it and get xserver, KVM and QEMU running there and connect it to network
- use your primary Windows computer to control this Linux virtual host computer remotely over the network

Trust me, you will be much more effective and productive with that setup, than trying to shoehorn you QEMU host onto Windows virtualized Linux.